# Invariant polynomials for a given irrep of SO(3)

Tags: representation-theory

**Background**

*Hilbert's basis theorem* says

> Given a compact lie group $G$ acting linearly on the space $\mathbb{R}^n$, there is a set of $G$-invariant homogeneous polynomials $\{p_1(x),\ldots,p_m(x)\}$, such that any $G$-invariant polynomial can be written as a polynomial in the $\{p_1(x),\ldots,p_m(x)\}$.

**Motivation [simplified and updated June 26, 2017]**

If we choose our Lie group to be $G=SO(3)$ acting on the space $\mathbb{R}^3$, the only invariant polynomial in $\{x_1,x_2,x_3\}$ is $$r^2 = x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2$$ and the powers thereof.

In the general case, $SO(3)$ acts on the space $\mathbb{R}^n$, through one of its $n$-dimensional irreducible representations. ($n = 2l + 1$, $\,l \in \mathbb{N}$).

**Question**

What are the invariants of $SO(3)$ when acting on $\mathbb{R}^{2l+1}$?

(I am still a bit green when it comes to representation theory, so feel free to gently suggest references or other reading material.)

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to answer my own question, at least in part.

I'll address "how to construct the invariants" since "what are the invariants" is a little vague. For example, I'm still working on understanding the intuition behind these invariants.

There's more to the story than I can post now, but this is a good start and gives a computationally efficient way of constructing the invariants. I'll add more to this as time goes on, if desired.

Here's how we make the invariants of $SO(3)$ for arbitrary representation index $\ell$ and of arbitrary degree $d$. (I cannot prove yet that it generates all the invariants, but I suspect that it does. It's based on a similar idea in a paper by Sattinger; I've simplified the method somewhat for our uses, cutting down on some steps.)

Let $F(\eta)$ be a $G$-invariant homogeneous polynomial of $\eta \in \mathbb{R}^n$. By $G$-invariance, for any $g \in G$,
$$
F(g.\eta) = F(\eta).
$$
$F(\eta)$ is a sum of monomials,
$$
F(\eta) = F_{ij \ldots k}\eta_i \eta_j \ldots \eta_k.
$$

Now let $t$ be one of the generators in the Lie algebra $L$ corresponding to $G$, and let $a$ be a parameter, so that we can write
$$
g = e^{a t} \,\,\, \forall g \in G.
$$
Then, expanding to first order in $a$,
$$
F(g.\eta) = F(e^{a t} .\eta) = F(\eta + a t .\eta) = F(\eta) + a t.\eta \cdot \nabla F(\eta).
$$

Evidently,
$$
t. \eta \cdot \nabla F(\eta) = 0.
$$

This is what we will use to solve the problem. Either we will find that the above dot product is zero identically, or it will give us a constraint on the coefficients of the monomials, producing an invariant.

This equation is a consequence of the following fact: the tangent space to an orbit is generated by the Lie operators, and the gradients of invariant functions are of course zero along the orbits -- so they must be perpendicular to them.

As a side note, we won't need to work with the most general sum of monomials; we only need to consider those which have
$$
i + j +  \ldots + k = 0.
$$

### Example, $\ell=1$, $d=2$

Let's do an example, the absolute simplest case. We will take $\ell=1$ and degree $d=2$.

For this case the most general invariant polynomial of degree $d = 2$ looks like
$$
F = a \eta_0^2 + b\eta_{-1}\eta_{1}.
$$
We have
$$
\nabla F = 
\begin{pmatrix}
b\eta_1 \\ 
2a \eta_0 \\ 
b\eta_{-1}
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Now let's consider what happens when we act on $\eta$ with one of the generators. We'll start with $L_z$, given by
$$
L_z = \begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
We have
$$
L_z \eta \cdot \nabla F = 
\begin{pmatrix}
-\eta_{-1} & 0 & \eta_1 
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
b\eta_1 \\ 
2a \eta_0 \\ 
b\eta_{-1}
\end{pmatrix}
=
-b \eta_{-1}\eta_{1} + b \eta_{-1}\eta_{1} = 0
$$
which equals zero identically. This won't help us. However, let's consider the case when we use the raising operator $L_+$,
$$
L_+ = \begin{pmatrix}
0& \sqrt{2} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \sqrt{2} \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
In this case,
$$
L_+ \eta \cdot \nabla F = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\sqrt{2} \eta_0 & \sqrt{2} \eta_1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
b\eta_1 \\ 
2a \eta_0 \\ 
b\eta_{-1}
\end{pmatrix}
=
\sqrt{2} b \eta_0 \eta_1 + 2\sqrt{2} a\eta_0 \eta_1 = 0.
$$
It follows that $b = -2a$, so that the most general second-order invariant for $\ell=1$ is (up to a multiplicative constant)
$$
F = \eta_0^2 - 2\eta_{-1}\eta_{1}.
$$

### Example, $\ell=2$, $d=3$

This is a less trivial example, but it can still be done by hand (more or less.)

The most general polynomial is
$$
F = a \eta_0^3 + b \eta_{-1}\eta_{0}\eta_{1} + c \eta_{-2} \eta_{0} \eta_{2} + d \eta_{-2}\eta_{1}^2 + e \eta_{-1}^2\eta_{2}.
$$
Operating on $\eta$ with $L_+$, where
$$
L_+ = \begin{pmatrix}
0& 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \sqrt{6} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \sqrt{6} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix},
$$
we have that the dot product $L_+ \eta \cdot \nabla F$ is equal to
$$
\begin{pmatrix} 
2 \eta_{-1} & \sqrt{6} \eta_0 & \sqrt{6} \eta_1 & 2 \eta_2 & 0 
\end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix}
c \eta _1^2+e \eta _0 \eta _2 \\
b \eta _0 \eta _1+2 d \eta _{-1}
   \eta _2 \\
3 a \eta _0^2+b \eta _{-1} \eta _1+e \eta _{-2} \eta _2\\
b \eta _{-1} \eta _0+2 c \eta _{-2} \eta _1\\
d \eta _{-1}^2+e \eta _{-2} \eta _0\\
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Carrying out the dot product, we get a linear system of equations for the variables $(a,b,c,d,e)$, represented by this equation:
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 3 \sqrt{6} & \sqrt{6} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & \sqrt{6} & 2 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 2 & 0 & 2 \sqrt{6} & 2 \\
 0 & 0 & 4 & 0 & \sqrt{6} \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
\begin{pmatrix}
a \\
b \\
c \\
d \\
e \\
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
0 \\
0 \\
0 \\
0 \\
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
I used Mathematica to row-reduce the above matrix. This yields
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{6} \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{1}{2} \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \frac{\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}}{2} \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & \frac{\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}}{2} \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
\begin{pmatrix}
a \\
b \\
c \\
d \\
e \\
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
0 \\
0 \\
0 \\
0 \\
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
We take $e$ to be the free parameter, which just plays the role of the overall multiplicative constant. Therefore
$$
F = -\frac{1}{6}\eta_0^3+\frac{1}{2} \eta_{-1} \eta_1 \eta_0+\eta_{-2} \eta_2 \eta_0-\frac{1}{2}
   \sqrt{\frac{3}{2}} \eta_{-2} \eta_1^2-\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}
   \eta_{-1}^2 \eta_2.
$$
This agrees with what I've calculated using a different method (due to Marko Jarić.)